# Styling checkbox when input is inside the label

Tags: css, input

I know how to style a checkbox using the `:checked + label` method. But this only applies if the label is independant of the input

```
<label>Label</label>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Is it possible to do the same level of styling if the input is wrapped in the label?

```
<label>
    label
    <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

I'd prefer a purely CSS method for doing this. No JS please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:has` pseudo-class.

- Lean more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
- Can I use : https://caniuse.com/css-has

```css
label:has(input:checked){
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<label>
    label
    <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Comment: Perfect. That is a handy class with decent browser coverage.